# Getting CPU time in Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu-11.10

I have a question on measuring CPU time on Ubuntu 12.04.

I want to use the CPU time as a stopping criteria in some loop. What is the best way?

```
while(....)
{
    //main part
    // get CPUTIME
    if(CPUTIME>= Given_Time)
    {
        break;         
    }

}
```

1) I can use `clock()`, if I don't care too much about the resolution of time.

```
time_t begin=clock();
....
time_t end=clock();

CPUTIME=(double)(end-begin)/(double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

However, `time_t` many be overflow, since the running time may be long(more than an hour). How can I fix this problem?

2) The second option is using `getrusage(int who, struct rusage *usage)`
Does it cost too much to call this function in the loop?

3) The third option is to use `int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespect *tp)`
So far, this is the best choice in my option.

Any suggestions and comments will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how fast your loop is running, you might not want to call the checking function every cycle. Perhaps add a loop counter and check the CPU time only if, for example, `(i % 1000) == 0`.

To answer your question: I'd personally use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, ...)` because `librt`, the library in which this function resides, was made specifically for tasks like this. However, there's no reason that you can't use the other two; you can easily detect the overflow with `clock()` by detecting when the value wraps and having a separate counter that counts the number of times it wraps.